# Pass `struct` as type name to function argument

Tags: json, reflection, interface, go

I'm writing some sort of RESTfull API based Object relational mapper in go.
I plan to make it MIT licensed, when i finish it.
The idea is to use some 3rd party REST API as data storage, and the `golang` client will query it for data needed.

The API responses are JSONs with known structure.

this is my code:

```
type AClient struct {
    Id        string `json:"id"`
    Uid       string `json:"uid"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastName"`
    CreatedAt string `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt string `json:"updatedAt"`
    City      string `json:"city"`
    Address   string `json:"address"`
    Telefone  string `json:"telefone"`
    Zip       string `json:"zip"`
    Telefon   string `json:"telefon"`
    Comment   string `json:"comment"`
}

type AEvents struct {
    Id          string    `json:"id"`
    Security    bool      `json:"security"`
    Description string    `json:"description"`
    Good        AGood     `json:"good"`
    Client      AClient   `json:"client"`
    Author      AAuthor   `json:"author"`
    InFuture    bool      `json:"inFuture"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
}

type Entry struct {
    AEvents //this have to be changed to `AClients` in runtime when needed
}

type ORM struct {
    ApiUrl         string
    ModelName      string
    ModelInterface Entry
    HuntKey        string
    HuntSid        string
    Csrf           string
}

func (o *ORM) Query(parameters map[string]string) ([]Entry, AMetadata, error) {
    responseParsed := struct {
        Status   string    `json:"status"`
        Metadata AMetadata `json:"metadata"`
        Data     []Entry   `json:"data"` //todo - use o.ModelInterface
    }{}
    client := &http.Client{}

    var queryString string

    for k, v := range parameters {
        queryString = queryString + fmt.Sprintf("%v=%v&", url.QueryEscape(k), url.QueryEscape(v))
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("%v%v?%v", o.ApiUrl, o.ModelName, queryString), nil)
    fmt.Println("---------------------------------------------")
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("[GET] %v%v?%v", o.ApiUrl, o.ModelName, queryString))
    req.Header.Set("huntKey", o.HuntKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, AMetadata{}, err
    }
    res, err1 := client.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    if err1 != nil {
        return nil, AMetadata{}, err1
    }
    if res.StatusCode == 200 {
        for _, v := range res.Cookies() {
            if v.Name == "XSRF-TOKEN" {
                o.Csrf = v.Value
            }
            if v.Name == "hunt.sid" {
                o.HuntSid = v.Value
            }
        }
        fmt.Printf("CSRF %v\n", o.Csrf)
        fmt.Printf("HuntSid %v\n", o.HuntSid)
        fmt.Println("---------------------------------------------")
        raw, err2 := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
        if err2 != nil {
            return nil, AMetadata{}, err2
        } else {
            err2 = json.Unmarshal(raw, &responseParsed)
            return responseParsed.Data, responseParsed.Metadata, nil
        }
    } else {
        return nil, AMetadata{}, errors.New("Unable to fetch data!")
    }
}
```

How can I make this:
When instantiating the  `ORM` object, how can i pass the struct name, that will be used to parse the JSON response. The current code works with the `struct` of `AEvents`, but i want it to be easy changeble t `AClient` and so on.

UPD: 
i have reviewed the code of https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm and find out tons of things how can i implement it.
Than, as i have promised, I publish this code as open source -https://github.com/vodolaz095/hrorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection, but be warned that it is non-trivial and relatively slow. I don't know of any other way.

- http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/
- http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

The simplest way to do this is to make your parameter of type `interface{}` and pass in an empty (uninitialized) instance of the struct you wish to unmarshal into. I highly suggest reading the second of the two links I list - it provides a clear introduction to reflection and how to use it for solving problems like this one.

Comment: thanks for answer, can you provide me some more insights how can i make it? i'm quite new to go, my previous language was javascript